# determining the time-stamp of sampled audio

Tags: c, alsa

I have inherited an application which samples audio using `snd_pcm_readn()`.
**What is the most reliable way to determine the time-stamp that should be associated with each sample retrieved?**

Presumably there will be some kind of buffering going on with ALSA or the capture card itself meaning clock_gettime() could have a variable error
(especially as this is a multi-threaded application).

It looks to me like it ought to be something like:

```
if((alsa_result = snd_pcm_readn(card->capture_handle,
         card->capture_buff,
         card->buffer_size)) == 0)
{

    snd_pcm_status_t pcm_status;
    snd_timestamp_t  snd_timestamp; //actually a struct timeval under the hood
    if (snd_pcm_status(card->capture_handle, &pcm_status) == 0)
    {
       snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp(&pcm_status, &snd_timestamp);
       // translate timeval into milliseconds
       const uint64_t millis = (snd_timestamp.tv_sec * (uint64_t)1000) + (snd_timestamp.tv_usec / 1000);
    }
```

}

However, to what time does snd_timestamp refer? Is it the first sample retrieved or the last one and do we need to account for samples that might have been captured since snd_pcm_readn() returned?

The ALSA documentation I have found is sketchy on the details. Is it even valid to use `snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp()` if time-stamps are not enabled (e.g. see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/sound/designs/timestamping.html).

Bonus points for references to good (preferably online) ALSA related reading material.

---

Related to this I cannot currently get the code above to compile as it says:

```
error: storage size of ‘pcm_status’ isn’t known
  snd_pcm_status_t pcm_status;
```

I have `#include <alsa/pcm.h>` and:

```
>grep -r _snd_pcm_status /usr/include/
/usr/include/alsa/pcm.h: typedef struct _snd_pcm_status snd_pcm_status_t;
```

but there seems to be no definition of `_snd_pcm_status` in an obvious location.

---

Update 11-Aug-2017

As pointed out snd_pcm_status_t is opaque and must be allocated by ALSA.
I still cannot quite get `snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp` to return the 'right' time-stamp:

```
//setup code...
if ((alsa_error = snd_pcm_sw_params_malloc(&sw_params)) < 0)
{
   //handle error
}
if ((alsa_error = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode(card->capture_handle, sw_params, SND_PCM_TSTAMP_ENABLE)) < 0)
{
   //handle error
}
if ((alsa_error = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode(card->capture_handle, sw_params, SND_PCM_TSTAMP_TYPE_GETTIMEOFDAY)) < 0)
{
   //handle error
}
snd_pcm_sw_params_free(sw_params);


// later on
if((alsa_result = snd_pcm_readn(card->capture_handle,
     card->capture_buff,
     card->buffer_size)) == 0)
{   
   time_t timeStamp = 0;
   snd_timestamp_t  snd_timestamp = {0,0}; //actually a struct timeval
   if (snd_pcm_status(card->capture_handle, card->status) == 0)
   {
       snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp(card->status, &snd_timestamp);
       timeStamp = snd_timestamp.tv_sec;
   }
}
```

timeStamp appears to be the monotonic clock rather than get time of day like I thought I was asking for (the ALSA docs do not specify).

I just got "1970-01-11T08:33:42: 894822"
which accords with:

cat /proc/timer_list | grep now
   now at 894831565155289 nsecs

I could just get a base time of `now - monotonic` but that seems wrong for a clock claiming to be SND_PCM_TSTAMP_TYPE_GETTIMEOFDAY. So I conclude my setup code or understanding is at fault somehow.

And is that the time-stamp of the samples I just readn() anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Timestamping must be enabled in the software params by calling `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode()` with `SND_PCM_TSTAMP_NONE`/`ENABLE`.

Timestamps can use different clocks; select one by calling `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_type()` with `SND_PCM_TSTAMP_TYPE_GETTIMEOFDAY`/`MONOTONIC`/`MONOTONIC_RAW`.

The timestamp of the last time the stream was started or stopped can be retrieved with `snd_pcm_status_get_trigger_tstamp()`. The timestamp of the last pointer update can be retrieved with `snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp()`. (The corresponding pointer position, with `snd_pcm_status_get_avail()`.)

`snd_pcm_status_t` is a hidden type because it can have different sizes in different library versions.
It must be allocated dynamically; see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861021/can-i-set-timestamp-in-alsa).

Comment: That helps but what does the "timestamp of the last pointer update" mean? I have retrieved some samples using snd_pcm_readn(). The 'pointer' is something internal to ALSA. Is this the time that my call unblocked and returned (i.e. the read pointer moved because I read something)? or when the buffer last got new audio (the write pointer moved)? I want to associate the samples I've read with a time-stamp matching when the audio reached the mic (allowing a small fixed offset). What I don't want to know is to when I last got data as that data could have been buffered for a variable period of time.

Comment: Also should we assume snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp() is undefined behaviour if snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode() is not set?

Comment: The hardware pointer is the position in the buffer where samples are read or written by the hardware. It is updated after each period, or when you ask for the status.